# What is the best way to convert Dictionary keys into variables with the dictionary values?

Tags: python, dictionary, variables

Can I convert dictionaries into variable-value pairs without `globals` or `locals` or `exec`, like:

```
count = { 'one':'first', 'two':'second'}
for key in count.keys():
    key = count.get(key)
```

Then I need:

```
print(one)
'first'
```

But it's not happening. can I do this? How?

Comment: why do you need `one` as variable, why do you need to store them as variables? As you know you can reach them by using keys as `count['one']`

Comment: Just out of curiosity why would you do that because accessing from ``dict`` would be easier.

Comment: I'm working with django. I would like to get all the form values using one loop. But request.POST is a dictionary, what is not useful in my case.

Comment: You shouldn't do this. Don't dynamically create variables. It's not even always possible. Only in global scopes (also class scopes) can you do this. You should just use your dictionary, or manually create the variables you need, i.e `one = count['one']; two = count['two']`

Answer (score 2):

I found this on Quora, worked for me.
Credit goes to Thu Yein Tun.

```
count = { 'one':'first', 'two':'second'}
for k, v in count.items():
    vars()[k] = v
```

https://qr.ae/pGBmlX

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to create an object, you can then use `getattr` and `setattr` to add and get its attributes much as you can with variables.

```
class Values(object):
    pass

obj = Values()

count = {'one':'first', 'two':'second'}

for key, value in count.items():
    setattr(obj, key, value)

print(getattr(obj, 'one'))
print(getattr(obj, 'two'))

# first
# second
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```py
for k,v in count.items():
    exec(f"{k}={repr(v)}")
```

example:

```
count = { 'one':'first', 'two':'second'}
for k, v in count.items():
    exec(f"{k}={repr(v)}")
print(one, two)
```

Comment: This does not work in general, e.g. in local scopes.

Answer (score 0):

I don`t understand why you would want to dynamically create variables, but in this case just use the keys from the dictionary as if you would have declared variables.

```
print(count.get("one","Unknown"))
```

The get function on a dictionary will handle KeyErrors and return a default value, which is specified in param 2. In this case it will look for key "one" in the count dict and then return the value, else it will return "Unknown". If parameter 2 is left blank, a null value will be returned